# validating multiple checkboxes with happy.js

Tags: jquery, happy.js

i'm using happy.js to validate a form. i need to validate that the user has clicked at least one of multiple checkboxes. THIS SYNTAX IS SPECIFIC TO HAPPY.JS.

what i'm trying to do with the following code is target all the checkboxes within a specific div, if at least one of them is checked, the form validates. if none are checked, form will throw an error.

appreciate any help.

within the happy.js methods, my custom function is:

```
   multiOption: function () {
    return $('#check_section > .checkbox').is(':checked').length >= 1;

    }
```

on the front end:

```
<div id="check_section">
   <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox"/>
   <input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
   <input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

the code doesn't seem to be able to locate the checkboxes. made this quick fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9fnC8/1/

Comment: You didn’t ask a question.

Comment: That syntax is not specific to `happy.js`. That is Javascript syntax.

Comment: well, happy.js is javascript so that's kind of a given, right?

Comment: @unfollow I don't think you understand what `specific` means. It means  `belonging uniquely to`, so when you say that the syntax is `specific` to `happy.js` you are stating that the syntax isn't general Javascript, but is some special syntax that only works with `happy.js`.

Comment: listen, not here to make enemies. i think your taking this a bit too seriously. and also, it's still implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[:checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
return $('#check_section > .checkbox:checked').length;
```

---

`$('#check_section > .checkbox:checked').length` will give the length of checked check-boxes.

If length is `0` it will return `false` if greater than `0` than return `true`

Comment: tried this a few different ways, didn't work but the logic behind it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "[is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)" function to "[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)":

```
 return $('#check_section > .checkbox').filter(':checked').length >= 1;
```

As the jQuery documentation states the "is" function returns true if one of the elements matches a selector.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

You could even remove the: `.length >= 1` and just return the result of the "is" call as this will be true if one or more of the checkboxes have been checked, and false if none have been checked.

**Edit:**

After seeing the markup provided by in your jsFiddle the issue is due to the `>` in your selector, the `>` means select child elements only.

As your checkboxes are not directly inside the `#check_section` element, but are actually contained within spans inside this element (making them grandchildren and not children of the `#check_section` element) the checkboxes you want are not included in the results.

Change your code to the following and it should work:

```
return $('#check_section .checkbox').filter(':checked').length >= 1;
```

Or

```
return $('#check_section .checkbox').is(':checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7FJw/2/

Comment: this is so close, but something is wrong about the initial locating .checkbox. i made a fiddle and it's not able to filter checked from unchecked: http://jsfiddle.net/9fnC8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Its the `>` selector. It selects elements that are a direct child of the parent, the .checkbox elements are not direct children (they are descendants) of #check_section (Here on SO they are, but in your fiddle they are not). the jQuery `.is()` returns a boolean (true of false) so doing the `length` of a boolean doesn't make sense. Simply doing

```
multiOption: function () {
    return $('#check_section .checkbox').is(':checked');

    }
```

should be what your after. As per fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S9wXx/)

Answer (score 0):

think i got it. i wasn't properly id-ing those checkboxes. noted if you're hunting children within the div you have to include the full path including any span tags that might be in the way.